# POST request to Wordpress REST API returns an empty object

Tags: php, reactjs, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api, wordpress-gutenberg

I am creating a `Gutenberg block` inside a plugin with a MediaUpload for zip files. Then I am trying to add a callback that will use the id of the zip file to get the attachment url, make a new folder in a separate assets area if there is not one yet, and unzip the file into the folder.

Right now I am trying to do this with REST using `wp.apiFetch`.

I've gotten as far as testing the response, but even though the response comes through properly, the object is empty.

**This is the `Edit.js` file:**

```
wp.apiFetch({
  path: '/name-support/v1/zipped/',
  method: 'POST',
  data: { id: 'test test test' },
}).then(data => {
  console.log('response: ', data);
});
```

**This is the REST API rout setup and the callback function:**

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
  register_rest_route( 'name-support/v1', '/zipped/', 
      [
        'methods' => WP_REST_Server::EDITABLE,
        'callback' => 'name_image_sequence_unzip',
        'permission_callback' => '__return_true'
      ] 
  );
});

function name_image_sequence_unzip($data) {
    return rest_ensure_response( $data );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue by specifying the content type in the headers option as application/json:

```
wp.apiFetch({
  path: '/name-support/v1/zipped/',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
  data: { id: 'test test test' },
}).then(data => {
  console.log('response: ', data);
});
```